# Does python have a better control structure or other feature to simplify the code?

Tags: python, control-structure

I'm new to Python and trying to write a validate function in the simple chest game to achieve:

> the a piece should move it's full extend (which mean in it's moving
>   direction like B7:E4, have a another piece F4 blocked, which is a
>   legal move )

[image]

```
def validate_move_rule(from_position, to_position, position_hash):
    blocker_position = []
    blocker_position.extend(position_hash)
    if(abs((int(to_position[1]) - int(from_position[1]))) == abs(ord(to_position[0]) - ord(from_position[0]))):
        if((int(to_position[1]) - int(from_position[1])) > 0 and (ord(to_position[0]) - ord(from_position[0])) > 0):
            next_position = str_plus(to_position[0],1) + str(int(to_position[1]) + 1)
            if(next_position in blocker_position):
                return True
        elif((int(to_position[1]) - int(from_position[1])) < 0 and (ord(to_position[0]) - ord(from_position[0])) < 0):
            next_position = str_plus(to_position[0],-1) + str(int(to_position[1]) - 1)
            if(next_position in blocker_position):
                return True
            #   left_up
        elif((int(to_position[1]) - int(from_position[1])) > 0 and (ord(to_position[0]) - ord(from_position[0])) < 0):
            next_position = str_plus(to_position[0],1) + str(int(to_position[1]) - 1)
            if(next_position in blocker_position):
                return True
            #left_down
        elif((int(to_position[1]) - int(from_position[1])) < 0 and (ord(to_position[0]) - ord(from_position[0])) > 0):
            next_position = str_plus(to_position[0], -1) + str(int(to_position[1]) + 1)
            if(next_position in blocker_position):
                return True
            #right_up
    elif(from_position[1] == to_position[1]):
        if((ord(to_position[0]) - ord(from_position[0])) > 0):
            next_position = str_plus(to_position[0],1) + to_position[1]
            if(next_position in blocker_position):
                return True
            #right
        elif((ord(to_position[0]) - ord(from_position[0])) < 0):
            next_position = str_plus(to_position[0],-1) + to_position[1]
            if(next_position in blocker_position):
                return True
            #left
    elif(from_position[0] == to_position[0]):
        if((int(to_position[1]) - int(from_position[1])) > 0):
            next_position = to_position[0] + str(int(to_position[1]) + 1)
            if(next_position in blocker_position):
                return True
            #down
        elif((int(to_position[1]) - int(from_position[1])) < 0):
            next_position = to_position[0] + str(int(to_position[1]) - 1)
            if(next_position in blocker_position):
                return True
            #up
    else:
        puts("Error: it's not a legal move(hint: must diagonal horizontal vertical)")
        return False
```

I found my code is really tedious, I thought Python should have some feature simplify my code, Any suggestion ?

Comment: I notice that you're converting back and forth between strings and integers... simplify your code by getting rid of the strings, just use integers.

Comment: If the piece always moves to full extend, why do you need to validate - move should just take argument `direction` instead of `x`,`y` and do `while next_spot_is_empty(): move_to_next_spot()`

Comment: You have too many `()` - Python doesn't need them especially in conditional statements. `if next_position in blocker_position:` is perfectly valid; you also don't need to check `> 0`, as any positive value is "truthy".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- use variables for the difference between the positions
- move the blocker_position check to the bottom
- you don't need blocker_position
- only use int()/str() at the beginning or end of the function
- in the middle section only figure out how much x and y change, not their value

Like so:

```
def validate_move_rule(from_position, to_position, position_hash):
    to_pos_x = ord(to_position[0])
    to_pos_y = int(to_position[1])
    delta_pos_x = to_pos_x - ord(from_position[0]) # x
    delta_pos_y = to_pos_y - int(from_position[1]) # y

    delta_x = 0
    delta_y = 0

    if abs(delta_pos_x) == abs(delta_pos_y): 
        # diagonal
        delta_x = 1 if delta_pos_x > 0 else -1
        delta_y = 1 if delta_pos_y > 0 else -1
    elif from_position[1] == to_position[1]: 
        # horizontal     
        delta_x = 1 if delta_pos_x > 0 else -1
    elif from_position[0] == to_position[0]: 
        # vertical     
        delta_y = 1 if delta_pos_y > 0 else -1
    else:
        puts("Error: it's not a legal move(hint: must diagonal horizontal vertical)")
        return False

    new_position = chr(to_pos_x + delta_x) + str(to_pos_y + delta_y)
    return new_position in position_hash
```

Comment: Other than this, I'd say the only other thing would be to write down the formulas and see if you can mathematically reduce the logic to something simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Think about a little table of booleans. Valid or not valid.